# Is this a valid sentence - 'The export quality tea is seldom used in the country'?

Tags: prepositions, indian-english

Please help me with this sentence...

> The export quality tea is seldom used in the country.

I think here 'of' should come after 'export'. Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Why do you think the sentence should contain 'if'?

Comment: @KillingTime sorry, there is not ```if``` . there is  ```of````

Comment: By definition, it is called "export quality tea" because it is intended for the export market, not for domestic consumption. The sentence makes no sense if 'of' is added, as "The export **of** quality tea is seldom used in the country." Anyway, it would be better without a definite article: "Export quality tea ..." is an uncountable noun phrase.

Comment: @WeatherVane then why not to use ```exported``` instead of ```export```

Comment: Because it isn't the quality which is exported, but the tea which is "export quality". If you look at some beer bottles, for example, they say "export" not "exported". There are descriptions of 'quality' such as "first quality", "second quality", "export quality".

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. Except that whether or not the sentence should start with the definite article *(**the**)* depends *entirely* on whether preceding text has specifically drawn a distinction between "export quality" tea and ***other*** grade[s] of tea. If that earlier distinction *has* been made, you can (but you don't *have to*) include the article. If not, including the article is non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The word "quality" is used in a few different ways. In full, we might say "low quality tea" or "high quality tea"; on its own, "quality tea" would mean "high quality tea".

In this case, "export quality" means something like "sufficiently high quality for export". It might also be called "export grade tea". So "export" is qualifying the "quality" or "grade", not the "tea" itself.

Comment: And I would add that, as it is a double-barreled adjective, it requires a hyphen: **export-quality tea**.

Comment: @randomhead [Google ngrams disagrees](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=export-quality%2Cexport+quality&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexport%20-%20quality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexport%20quality%3B%2Cc0). I think "export" is best analysed as modifying "quality" in the same way as "high", and in the same way that "dark" or "Navy" can modify "blue".

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct, but have different meanings.

"The export quality tea..." means tea that is of an appropriate quality to export. "Export" modifies "quality" to tell us what quality the tea is.

"The export of quality tea..." means the action of exporting tea that is good quality. "Export" is the subject of the sentence, and "of quality tea" modifies "export".